# How to provide my Jenkins Project access to another Jenkins user

Tags: jenkins

Respected Sir,

I have a query. I have a project which I have created in my jenkins. There is a friend of mine in different location. How do I make sure that he can get access of my jenkins project into his.

The reason I am asking this question is we two are in different places. So once I run my automation scripts in jenkins the cucumber report will be delivered to his email address. So for him to access the console output and build I need to provide access correct? Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated

Respected Sir,

I have a query. I have a project which I have created in my jenkins. There is a friend of mine in different location. How do I make sure that he can get access of my jenkins project into his.

The reason I am asking this question is we two are in different places. So once I run my automation scripts in jenkins the cucumber report will be delivered to his email address. So for him to access the console output and build I need to provide access correct? Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated

Comment: Are you asking about how you can provide authentication, or how you can expose your Jenkins server to someone on a different network?

Comment: Yes, how to expose my Jenkins server to someone on a different network? Any help on this will be highly appretiated

Comment: If you are not on the same network then it is going to be a very complex task